# How to validate and handle a form in Express (NodeJS)

Tags: forms, node.js, express

Is there a preferred form handling and validation library for Express?

I'm really looking for a similar level of abstraction as is found in Django forms - i.e. validation and error reporting in the template.

If the same validation could be used on the client side, that would be great.

Has anyone used, or written, anything good?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like there's a module for this located at https://github.com/caolan/forms.  I've never used it, but it seems fairly full featured.

Comment: i don't like the idea of someone else controlling my form markup.

Comment: @chovy: You should read the doc more carefully instead of leading everyone in the wrong direction. When you render your form with form.toHTML() of field.toHTML(), you can pass a custom iterator in parameter. The iterator is the function that toHTML will use to render the form/field. You can make custom widgets, validators, iterators and more...

Comment: You both have a point. Expanding on what @chovy said, even if you pass an iterator you're indicating that the form must be rendered using `.toHTML()`. Contrary to that and expanding on what @Jean-Philippe said, you actually don't even need to use `.toHTML()` to get almost everything you need to deal with your forms (though it took a very careful reading of the docs to figure that out).

Answer (score 7):

This also looks viable and is still being developed: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator

Here's an example of validating a form submission (login post request):

```
exports.login.post = function(req, res){
  req.assert('username', 'Enter username').notEmpty();
  req.assert('password', 'Enter password').notEmpty();
  res.locals.err = req.validationErrors(true);

  if ( res.locals.err ) {
    if ( req.xhr ) {
      res.send(401, { err: res.locals.err });
    } else {
      res.render('login', { err: res.locals.err });
    }

    return;
  }

 //authenticate user, data is valid
};
```