# Passing variables on res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there an easy way to pass a variable with a res.redirect in node.js / express without having to append it to the URL, or store it in a cookie, or session variable?

Why do I want to do this? Here is an example:

Let's say I have a users page at /users. And I can add users at the page /users/add. I post the form at /users/add, if it has errors it reloads that form with the error messages, if it goes through successfully, it redirects back to the /users page. What I want is the ability to know I just added a user and show a success message for it.

Here is an example of a post:

```
exports.usersAddPost = function(req, res, next) {
  // validate form

  if (!validated) {
     // go back to form
     return res.render('users/add', req.body.whatever);
  } else {
     // go back to users list
     // need some way to tell users page that a user was just added
    return res.redirect('users');
  }
};
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate question. Trying it out now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079048/passing-error-message-to-template-through-redirect-in-express-node-js?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually decided to use sessions since I found a nice way to do it fairly elegantly.

Before the redirect I set the session like so:

```
req.session['success'] = 'User added successfully';
res.redirect('users');
```

And on the users page I check for a success variable and pass that to my template if it exists, and then to reset it I just set it to null. This works perfectly for what I need.

Comment: Will this work for all users, for example, someone who is not logged in?

Comment: You don't need to be logged in for sessions to work, so yes this works for someone who is not logged in. That said I use a different session variable to determine if someone is logged in, and if they aren't logged in they can't access this page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, you could use the http referer and assume a user was just added, since according to your workflow that's the only way it could happen:

```
document.referrer == "/users/add"
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good option since referrer comes from the browser, and can be disabled IIRC. Also, I would prefer a server side solution.

Comment: Well technically everything can be disabled, even javascript hehe. But OK, if you want to keep the flow in the server why don't you render the users page (instead of doing a redirect) as a 201 Created response, with a Location header, and use that info (status/location) to show some special message in your template.

Comment: I found a solution that works pretty well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you explain the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What about just displaying simple html with a meta refresh? Example:

```
function redirectFlash(url, timeout, msg) {
  var defaultTimeout = 5;
  if (typeof timeout === 'string') {
    msg = timeout;
    timeout = defaultTimeout;
  } else if (timeout === undefined) {
    msg = '';
    timeout = defaultTimeout;
  }
  return '<html><head><title>Redirecting ...</title><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'
         + timeout
         + ';url='
         + url
         + '"></head><body>'
         + msg
         + '<br /><a href="'
         + url
         + '">Click here to return manually</a></body></html>';
}

exports.usersAddPost = function(req, res, next) {
  // validate form

  if (!validated) {
     // go back to form
     return res.render('users/add', req.body.whatever);
  } else {
     // go back to users list
     // need some way to tell users page that a user was just added
    return res.end(redirectFlash('/users', 'User added successfully. Returning you to the user list ...'));
  }
};
```

Comment: This feels like a solution that might have been okay 15 years ago, but I don't see this as being a good user experience. I have found a solution. I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: I think it's still ok, especially since you mentioned no url parameters, no session storage, and no cookies. :-)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really leave room for much.