# What is the simplest and/or best way to send data between routes in node.js express?

Tags: node.js, routes

My setup is like this:

I get data from omDB using a omdb lib from github, this whole parts looks like this:

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res) {

    var omdb = require('omdb');

    var title = req.body.title;

    omdb.get( {title: title}, true, function(err, movie){
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        if(!movie) {
            return console.log('No movie found');
        }

        //console.log('%s (%d)', movie.title, movie.year);

        result = movie.title+movie.year+movie.poster;

        console.log(result);

        res.redirect('/result');
    })


});
```

And then i want to use the result from that post request in another route:

```
router.get('/result', function(req, res) {

    res.render('result', { title: title});

});
```

What is the best and hopefully simplest approach to do this, consider that I am a node.js noob.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing error message to template through redirect in Express/Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079048/passing-error-message-to-template-through-redirect-in-express-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using express.js, you could use the [session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware:

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res) {

    var omdb = require('omdb');

    var title = req.body.title;

    omdb.get( {title: title}, true, function(err, movie){
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        if(!movie) {
            return console.log('No movie found');
        }

        //console.log('%s (%d)', movie.title, movie.year);

        req.session.result = {
            title: movie.title,
            year: movie.year,
            poster: movie.poster
        };

        res.redirect('/result');
    })


});
```

then:

```
router.get('/result', function(req, res) {

    if (req.session.result) {

        var result = req.session.result;
        req.session.result = null;
        res.render('result', { movie: result });

    }
    else {

        // Redirect to error page.

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this when I have gotten some food in me!

Comment: I get the error Cannot set property 'result' of undefined. I have installed express-session and made a var session= require('express-session')

Comment: You need to initialize the middleware - check out the examples in the repo's README.

Comment: A side note tho, do you know why my img src tag isnt getting rendered? Thanks for all the help btw :)

Comment: No problem. I'd have to see your code in order to help you. Maybe opening another question would be a better idea than continuing this discussion here in the comments!